OOM error when training transformer model
Im working on a HMER (handwritten mathematical expression recognition) problem and I tried to use a CNN- transformer architecture. However, when I try to train my model, I encounter this error:
DefaultCPUAllocator: not enough memory: you tried to allocate 69271363584 bytes.
I think there is some problem with my positional encoding but i'm honestly confused on how to debug this or what is the real problem here (im a very much beginner at this)
my current model looks like this
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, max_len=5000):
        super(PositionalEncoding, self).__init__()
        self.encoding = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float() * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model))
        self.encoding[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        self.encoding[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        self.encoding = self.encoding.unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

    def forward(self, x):
        seq_len = x.size(1)
        return x + self.encoding[:, :seq_len, :].to(x.device)

class TransformerDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, d_model, num_heads, num_layers, max_seq_length):
        super(TransformerDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, d_model)
        self.positional_encoding = PositionalEncoding(d_model, max_seq_length)
        decoder_layer = nn.TransformerDecoderLayer(d_model=d_model, nhead=num_heads)
        self.transformer_decoder = nn.TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer, num_layers=num_layers)
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(d_model, vocab_size)

    def forward(self, target_seqs, memory, target_mask):
        # Embed target sequences
        embedded = self.embedding(target_seqs)  # (batch, seq_len, d_model)
        embedded = checkpoint(self.positional_encoding, embedded)  # Add positional encoding
        # Transpose for compatibility with nn.TransformerDecoder (seq_len, batch, d_model)
        embedded = embedded.permute(1, 0, 2)
        memory = memory.permute(1, 0, 2)
        # Decode
        decoded = checkpoint(self.transformer_decoder, embedded, memory, target_mask)  # (seq_len, batch, d_model)
        # Transpose back to (batch, seq_len, d_model)
        decoded = decoded.permute(1, 0, 2)
        # Final output layer
        logits = checkpoint(self.fc_out, decoded)  # (batch, seq_len, vocab_size)
        return logits


Is there anything wrong with my code? and if not, what might be causing the problem im having

This appears to be happening because you code is attempting to assign a variable which is going to take up ~64GB - which is larger than your machines RAM. You either need to reduce the batch size of your data processing or massively increase the machine RAM, or increase the page file size (windows)
